# Let the user navigate an external website (that refuses to be within iframe) from my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have this situation:

[image]

So I want let the user navigate, from within my website, an external website, and I want to analyze the DOM of that website because I need the information within it.

I am not doing nothing to illegal, but only for work :)

The external website is designed in a way to "break out" an iframe. I tried to sandboxing the iframe, but the response received by the website has the same origin header, so I can't.

I kindly ask if someone worked with those situations and has some tips.
Example: I have to implement something on html page, or I have to implement something on webserver...I don't know.

Thanks to all!!!

Comment: You could proxy the request to that website, maybe at great cost, and interact with its DOM as you see fit doing so.

Comment: @Calimero: I'm sorry but I haven't so much experience in proxy..so your suggestion is: set up a proxy on web server, when the user clicks, for example, a link to the external website, that request goes through the proxy on server and I can read the response of the external website? But what about if I want let the user to navigate on the external website and get the DOM information only when I find a specified html element on a page of the external website?

Comment: basically yes. With a properly set up reverse proxy, you can (and probably will have to) rewrite each page at your convenience before presenting it to the user, and search for html tags or whatever. Note that it might be a lot of work for a solution far from being perfect, but that might be your only option if you don't have control over anything.